# Prevent page from displaying

Tags: pages

I would like to be able to prevent a page from displaying in wordpress based upon a future date.

Is this possible without using a plugin?

Comment: Please explain more. It's not clear now.

Comment: It is possible without using a plugin via core WordPress functions. It is not possible via the page publishing module in admin cp.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `date_query` parameter in a query[1](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters). Make sure you query posts that are both the age you require and currently public.

Set the post status to private[2](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status#Private) with the `wp_insert_post()`[3](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) function.

Here's an example from the codex which should give you an idea for how to query for posts older than a certain date:[1](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters)

**Return posts made over a year ago but modified in the past month**

```
$args = array(
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'column' => 'post_date_gmt',
            'before' => '1 year ago',
        ),
        array(
            'column' => 'post_modified_gmt',
            'after'  => '1 month ago',
        ),
    ),
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Additionally, you can add the `wp_safe_redirect()`[4](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_safe_redirect) function to private pages to redirect them elsewhere if the post is private. You can create a condition similar to this[5](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_status#Examples) in a page template, for example, to check the status:

```
if ( get_post_status ( $ID ) == 'private' ) {
    echo 'private';
} else {
    echo 'public';
}
```